# What is the bootsect equivalent for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I'm having trouble getting Windows XP and Ubuntu dual boot to work on an Ideapad S205.
Fortunately I found people with similar issues and a possible solution.
The solution is posted here:
http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Ideapad-S205-GRUB-EFI-trouble/m-p/443629/highlight/true#M2965

I'm currently stuck on steps 8-9 
because the diskpart that comes with Windows XP does not support activating partitions. Nor does it have the bootsect tool.

```
8. bootsect /nt60 C:

9. diskpart --> select disk 0 --> select partition 3 --> active --> exit
```

Are there equivalent tools for XP or do I have to boot with some other ISO to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Vista or Windows 7 ISO to boot from for those tools. As long as you stay in WinPE, you won't damage your XP install.

However, with `bootsect.exe`, you need to pass `/nt52` instead of `/nt60` for it to work with XP.

Comment: ok, i followed the instructions but no signs of grub on boot :/, thank you for the WinPE knowledge, though.

Comment: Well, `bootsect.exe` will rewrite the MBR, so losing Grub would be somewhat expected.  You might need to boot an Ubuntu live CD/USB and reinstall grub.  I'm surprised that there'd be any problems installing Ubuntu after Windows 7, but I don't spend enough time with Ubuntu to know how to help you out more.